# jsf h:message position like rich:message

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

when I'm using `rich:message` inside my form , I see the message just under the input field , colored in red and with X picture.

My question is how can I position `h:message` to be in the same exact place like `rich:message`? or alternately, to delete the X picture from the rich:message.
(I want to be able to see a red text just under the input field, without any picture).

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html#sect-Component_Reference-richmessage-Appearance) which explains exactly how to remove the `rich:message` icon. 
It is not mention there , but when refering a css file it should be after the pages loads, so i used `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"/>`.
hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you use RichFaces, they provide you with nice styling for your `message` component. If you don't want to use it, you have to build your own CSS style class to format the message component. Original JSF 's `<h:message>` component has the attribute `styleClass`. You can implement how you want it to look like with CSS class and put the class name there like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .message { 
      background-color: red;
   }
</style> 

<h:inputText id="myInput" />
<h:message for="myInput" styleClass="message" />

<h:panelGrid columns="3">
   <h:outputText value="Input " />
   <h:inputText id="myInput" />

   <h:outputText />
   <h:message for="myInput" styleClass="message" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

My example will not display as nice as RichFaces's implementation. You need to figure it out yourself :P.

Comment: I know that.. this is why i asked just how to position it under the input , or to delete the picture form the `rich:message` .. thank's any way.

Comment: @user590586: I updated my answer with 2 ways to make the message appear under your input :P

Comment: thank's! I tried it before also, but i think it's to complicated to do it for each input inside my form.. I'm tring to position it with style and not by adding an empty `output` for each `input`. any idea? thank's.

Comment: Do you really want to do it with style? It may be very troublesome. If you use `<h:panelGrid>`, you can use its `columnClasses` attribute to specify the style class of each column. The remaining is about implmenting the style class for `<h:message>` & `<h:inputText>` to alter their position. ^^ You can try!

Comment: o.k.. so what about just deleting the `X` icon picture from the `rich:message` ? is this possible?

Comment: @user590586: hmmm this may be also quite difficult. If RichFaces's `message` component does not provide any attribute to turn of the image, you would need to go into RichFace's source code and figure out where they implemented the style class for their `message` component and make changes to it.